# How to change owner of an appengine application (moving/selling it to a new company)

Tags: google-app-engine, admin, verification, account

I have developed an AppEngine application that I am transferring to a different company, and I would like to remove my own personal access from this application after the transfer to the other company is complete.

The first step that I took in transferring the ownership was to invite the other person as an administrator with an "Owner" Role.

However, after the transfer, beside my name in the Admin/Permissions console, I see the message "The only SMS verified owner cannot be removed" - which appears to make it impossible to remove myself as an owner from the application.

It seems that the other "owner" cannot verify their account via SMS, since they already have administrator access to the application.

How can the other account get "SMS verified" so that we can then remove my account as an administrator from the AppEngine application?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try having the new owner of the application to create a new application on [appengine.google.com](http://appengine.google.com), that should trigger the SMS verification flow if their account is not yet verified.

If they have any issues verifying their number, they should use the form linked at the bottom of the [SMS Verification for App Creation FAQ](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/sms).

Comment: Still required to do this to trigger SMS-verified status on a user one year later.