# Transferring GAE app from one Google Apps account to another

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps, google-account

Is it possible to transfer a Google App Engine app from one open Google Apps account to another open account?

Alternatively, if I delete the app from one account, will the app identifier name become available to register with the other account as a new app?

I saw this question and associated answers related to closed accounts: [Google App Engine - Transfer Application From A Closed Account To Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655307/google-app-engine-transfer-application-from-a-closed-account-to-another)

Can anyone advise on this with respect to scenarios in which both accounts are still open and active?

Comment: related: [How to change owner...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796611/how-to-change-owner-of-an-appengine-application-moving-selling-it-to-a-new-comp)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can transfer a GAE app by adding the user you want to transfer it to to the permissions list as an owner, then log in as that user and remove the original owner.

App IDs never get recycled, so deleting an app will not make the app id available again.

Comment: That's the way to do it.. :)

Comment: Any idea how to SMS verify the new user I add as owner? I'm unable to remove the existing user because it says that I cannot remove the only owner who is SMS verified - but I can't figure out how to verify the new user.

Comment: i think if that new user tries to create a new app it will prompt them to sms verify then. so just create an app with an obscure appid (ie don't take one that someone else might want!)